# Octave map over matrix with row and column indexes

Tags: functional-programming, octave

So basically I'm looking for something like `arrayfun(@(value, rowIdx, colIdx), matrix)`.

I need to create one matrix from another based on it's values and their indexes, is there a way to avoid for-loops?

Comment: Can you show us an actual example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create matrices for the row and column indices using `meshgrid` and the size of your matrix. You can then use all three of these matrices to calculate the result.

```
[col_index, row_index] = meshgrid(1:size(matrix, 1), 1:size(matrix, 2));

% Now do some calculations using that
new_matrix = matrix + row_index * col_index;
```